React Native: 'main' has not been registered Error with Hermes Engine
I'm encountering an issue in my React Native project where I'm consistently getting the error message "main has not been registered" when using the Hermes JavaScript engine. The error occurs during development, and I'm unable to proceed due to this issue.
Here's the specific error message:
ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I've tried various troubleshooting steps such as clearing the Metro cache, recreating the cache, and restarting the project. However, the error persists.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve the "main has not been registered" error, especially when using the Hermes engine in React Native? Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you.
This is my package.json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --port 54842",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "^51.0.8",
    "expo-av": "^14.0.5",
    "expo-file-system": "^17.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "^16.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.12.1",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "js-base64": "^3.7.7",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.1.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.2",
    "redux": "^5.0.0",
    "string-similarity-js": "^2.1.4",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "vokok-app",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}

and app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "vokok-app",
    "slug": "vokok",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-av",
        {
          "microphonePermission": "Allow ${PRODUCT_NAME} to access your microphone"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/sta_header_logo_rec.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.stormstudy.vokok",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
      "permissions": [
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
      ]
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.stormstudy.vokok",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon_android.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "INTERNET",
        "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "port": 57577
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "fedf46ea-d30c-4f1b-8fb9-4b285ff246dd"
      }
    }
  }
}


AppEntry.js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { AppRegistry, Platform } from 'react-native';
import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);


I thought there might be an issue with AppEntry.js, so I tried using both registerRootComponent and AppRegistry, but it failed.

Next, I thought it could be a dependency issue, so I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json, then reinstalled them properly, but the problem persisted.



I think your project is running is any different folder.
I mean please be confirm you run project in same folder where your react native project.
Am assuming that your project name is 'Demo' then your must run 'npm start ' and 'npm run android' or 'npm run ios' command in same directory terminal or cmd.

I'm encountering the same issue. Any update on this? :)
